# proper version of Spring JUnit runner - Spring 3.1.2 - JUnit 4.3.1

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, junit, weblogic-10.x

I am using Oracle Weblogic 10 for a legacy project, the IDE has a plugin for JUnit 4.3.1 and the project uses Spring 3.1.2 .. I want to start creating test cases for the project using Junit .. Now I am not able to annotate the test class with the popular `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` because the class is `The type org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` .... I checked the `junit.jar` that is in the eclipse plugin, It doesn't contain `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` ... also I replace the `junit`  jar with junit 4.5 which contains `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` ... but the work space didn't build 
So which version of junit is appropriate with spring 3.1.2 and how to bootstrap it ?

Comment: I am able to use junit 4.12 with spring 3. And the annotation SpringJUnit4CladsRunner.

Comment: Aha yes thank you, I noticed finally that the IDE was caching so I needed just to clean and re build all related projects

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the newest version: JUnit 4.12. If it doesn't work it is not a problem of JUnit not Spring. Feel free to post any errors if it still does not work.